# asp.net mvc 5 redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net project that when I call it like: (h*tp://localhost/Home)
shows the home page, but when I do `http://localhost/` I get a redirect loop. I thought it was related to that recently I added authentication to it, so I removed all `[Authorize]` attributes from all controllers, but still the same problem. I haven't changed anything on the routes.

Any ideas on the problem could be?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and 
*the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I stated the problem. An asp.net mvc website should serve the same page if you request http://example.com or http://example.com/home, and when I omit the /home I get a redirect loop which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @zaidorx Im going to take a guess and say its your error handler trying to redirect to the error page and its getting caught in a redirection loop. Are you overriding the OnException method by any chance?

Comment: What would be helpful is to know what the redirect loop is redirecting to.

Comment: it is always redirecting to it self.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was actually something really weird(probably because of my lack of knowlge with mvc). In the controller that handle the login and logout, somehow I delete part of the route attribute for the logout action. 
it should say

```
[GET("logout")]
public ActionResult logout()...
```

and it was

```
[GET("")]
```

After fixing that the redirect loop stopped and everything started to work as expected.
What I still don't understand is that none of my controllers were using the [Authorize] attribute, so I think that logout should have never been executed. 
For the sake of future reference, if anybody could bring some light into this, it will be great.
Thanks to everybody that tried to help me.